# How to open web links of a textview with in my app itself

Tags: android-studio, linkify

I'm using Linkify to make the web links clickable inside my textview.
But the problem is when I click on those links, they are opening in default browser.
But I want to open those links within my app like Gmail (when we open links of an email links will be opened with in Gmail app).

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.result);
      textView.setText("http://example.com Testing Linkify for web links");
      Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
   }
}
```

Can any one help me...

Comment: Do you find any solution?